# Why is it not changing values of that variables?

Tags: c++, class, object

I have to change this program so that data of object star show actually name and  nr_indeksu but i'am stuck. Any help? And sorry for variables names but in my laguage they have meaning believe me and for the mess.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class student
{
private:
string imie_nazwisko_ = "NO_NAME";
unsigned int nr_indeksu_ = 0;
public:
student(string imie_nazwisko, unsigned int nr_indeksu);
void printDane()
{
cout << " Metoda printDane klasy bazowej" << endl;
cout << " imie nazwisko " << imie_nazwisko_ << endl;
cout << " nr indeksu " << nr_indeksu_ << endl;
}
};
class starosta : public student
{
public:
string imie_nazwisko_ = "NO_NAME";
unsigned int nr_indeksu_ = 0;
string email_ = "no@noemail";
void printDane()
{
cout << " Metoda printDane klasy starosta" << endl;
cout << " imie nazwisko " << imie_nazwisko_ << endl;
cout << " nr indeksu " << nr_indeksu_ << endl;
cout << " email "<< email_<<endl;
}
starosta(string imie_nazwisko, unsigned int nr_indeksu, string email);
};
starosta::starosta(string imie_nazwisko, unsigned int nr_indeksu, string email) :student(imie_nazwisko, nr_indeksu), email_(email)
{
cout << "Tworzenie obiektu klasy starosta "<< endl;
}
student::student(string imie_nazwisko, unsigned int nr_indeksu) : imie_nazwisko_(imie_nazwisko)
{
nr_indeksu_ = nr_indeksu;
cout << "Tworzenie obiektu klasy student" <<endl;
}
int main()
{
student stud("Jan Kowalski",7);
stud.printDane();
starosta star("Aleksandra Nowak",999,"mail@nomail.dot");
cout << "Dane:" << star.imie_nazwisko_ << " " << star.nr_indeksu_ << endl;
star.printDane();
}
```

Comment: Please apply indentation to your code, it will make reading, understanding and improving it much easier for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

You declare new members in the class `starosta` that already exist in the class `student`. Then you initialize the members of `student` using its constructor and try to print out the members of `starosta` in its method `printDane`. You should remove duplicated names from the class `starosta`.

```
class starosta : public student
{
 public:
  string imie_nazwisko_ = "NO_NAME";  // duplicates student::imie_nazwisko_
  unsigned int nr_indeksu_ = 0; // duplicates student::nr_indeksu_
```